# SonarQube maintain different version of application

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-scan

In Corporate world, in many cases we need to maintain at least two version of application: 
- current production version
- development

The only way to setup SonarQube is to have two projects with different ids. Is there any better way of doing it?

I've already tested scenario with one project but different  `sonar.projectVersion` - there is no distinguish between version on fronted.

Any propositions?

Answer (score 1):

The use of the `sonar.branch` analysis parameter to distinguish two different branches within the SonarQube server is the closest there is to branch support right now.

BTW, analyzing with two different `sonar.projectVersion` values is simply going to successively overwrite the same project.

Comment: I know this property. But this will be new project:

```Two branches of the same project are considered to be different projects in SonarQube```

Comment: I am not sure about 5.1 but in 5.6 > for simple version comparsion you should be able to use compare projects - under main menu - more.